# Infinite Scroll do Jetpack com problema de paginação

Tags: wordpress, rolamento

Em minha instalação do Wordpress estou usando o plugin JETPACK e sua feature Infinite scroll.

Na pagina inicial do blog, eu estou usando a action pre_get_posts e o filter infinite_scroll_query_args para alterar a Query e fazer puxar postagens comuns e um custom post type.

O problema é que com isso a paginação do infinite scroll quebra e só contabiliza a paginação do custom post type que estou usando, porém puxando ambos os post type normalmente. Onde era para o infinite scroll ser ativado 48 vezes, ele só ativa 8 vezes.

Estou usando o seguintes códigos:

```html
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'function_pre_post' );

function function_pre_post( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'critica' ) );
    }
}

function jetpack_infinite_scroll_query_args( $args ) {
    $args['post_type']   = array( 'post', 'critica' );
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'infinite_scroll_query_args', 'jetpack_infinite_scroll_query_args', 100 );
```

Comment: "só contabiliza a paginação do custom post type que estou usando", isso na página inicial? O que vc chama de "CPT que estou usando"?

Comment: Sim era da pagina inicial e TAMBEM das Archive, A Cpt que estou usando é o "Criticas".
Porem eu estava usando a versão 4.5 do plugin, após atualizar o plugin para a versão 4.7.2 a paginação voltar a funcionar normalmente.